# How to play an animation by using button in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div named `loading` at the starting of the body with `z-index` higher than that of all the inner div's in html. Inside the div, I have placed two gif images "one resembles launching gif and another is loading gif".

**HTML**

```
 <div id="loading">
    <img id="loading-image1" src="csi_files/loadsite2.gif" alt="Loading..." />
    <img id="loading-image2" src="csi_files/loadsite4.gif" alt="Loading..." />
 </div>
```

I have used the following javascript code to run the animation for 8 seconds. But the problem is the animation should be played only after clicking a button.

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#loading").remove()},8000);
        $(".left_links").click(function(e) {
        $(".contents_div").hide();
        var activeDivId = $(this).attr("id") + "_div";
        $("#" + activeDivId).show();
        window.mlPushMenu._resetMenu();
    });
});
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where, precisely, are you stuck? Incidentally that seems to be jQuery (which is a JavaScript *library*), you may want to add that tag to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle it by a button like this

```
$(function() {
   $('button').click(function () {
      setTimeout(function(){
        $("#loading").remove()},8000);
   });
   $(".left_links").click(function(e) {
       $(".contents_div").hide();
       var activeDivId = $(this).attr("id") + "_div";
       $("#" + activeDivId).show();
       window.mlPushMenu._resetMenu();
   });
});
```

The code would only execute if button is clicked.

To handle the event inside the button HTML itself, write this

```
$(function () {
   function animationHandle() {
      // animation code here. i.e. setTimeout code.
   }
});
```

...in the HTML write this

```
<button type="button" onclick="animationHandle()">
```

This would do the trick.

Comment: I'm new to javascript. So can you write the code for button?

Comment: @siddiQUE'S, the `$('button').click(function () { ... });` thing is the JS code for Button! :)

Comment: I asked the code for button inside body tag                     <button type="button" onclick=" ">                                 What i have to write inside the onclick?

Comment: Why are you defining `animationHandle()` inside the handler to `$(document).ready`? Shouldn't it be outside?